# Plotly Choropleth combined with ScatterGeo

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas, choropleth

Can anyone help me spot the error here?

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties,
        locations=df_se['FIPS'], z=df_se['use_values'],
        colorscale="Viridis", zmin=min(df_se['use_values']), zmax=max(df_se['use_values']),
        marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0
    ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergeo(
        lon = df_jake['lng'],
        lat = df_jake['lat'],
        text = df_jake['Name']+', '+df_jake['Link'],
        mode = 'markers'
    ))
fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

It just shows up blank. I can plot Chloropleth and ScatterGeo seperately however

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of context: `Choroplethmapbox` makes choropleths on tile maps ([example](https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/)), whereas `Scattergeo` makes points on outline maps ([example](https://plot.ly/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/)).

The scatter counterpart to `Choroplethmapbox` is `Scattermapbox` ([example](https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/)) and the choropleth counterpart to `Scattergeo` is `Choropleth` ([example](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/)).

So the answer likely depends on what you are trying to do: if you're trying to show a choropleth and scatter data on a tile map, you'll want to switch from `Scattergeo` to `Scattermapbox` and if you want to show this data on an outline map, you'll want to switch from `Choroplethmapbox` to `Choropleth`.

Comment: I still cannot figure out a way to overlay a `go.Scattergeo()` using `.shp` json using the geojson argument and overlay that with longitudes and latitudes of say, stores, using the arguments `lon` andl `lat` under the same function. All three of these arguments are available and the execution does not trigger any exceptions. Just like @mustacheMcGee said I can produce two separate map plots but the combination does not work.